# How to change keyboard layout of macbook pro during first run registration?

Tags: keyboard

I'm running the registration after turning on my new macbook pro for the first time. I've chosen my national keyboard layout and now I can't write @ or + signs. I don't know how to change keyboard layout, some shortcuts like cmd space or cmd alt space don't work. Please notice that I also need to write national characters, so going back and choosing english keyboard layout won't work.

Comment: To which locale did you set the keyboard? Anybody here look up the position of @ and + for you if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use the czech keyboard:

**normal**

[image]

with **shift key** pressed

[image: **enter image description here**]

with **option key** pressed

[image]

Comment: Aaaah, option key is what I was looking for, thanks (I'm new to mac world...)